# Remove item from session (show a remove button)

Tags: php, session

I have a button on a page, It's a simple input submit button, which sends the page ID to a form on another page to save it in a PHP session.

I was wondering how I'd go about showing a remove button instead if that item is already in your session?

This is the code that the form gets sent to

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!in_array($_POST['event_id'], $_SESSION['event_orders'])) {
    $_SESSION['event_orders'][] = $_POST['event_id'];
}
?>
```

The page with the button doesn't actually have any session code, but I guess it would be a similar IF kind of statement, but I am unsure of the exact syntax I should use? And how would it take the ID away from session?

EDIT:

Would something like this work? To put around the form button.

```
<? if(isset($_SESSION['event_orders']))
{
    echo "<a href='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?delete'>delete</a>";
}
else if(!in_array($_POST['event_id'], $_SESSION['event_orders'])) {
    // echo the submit button;
} ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use unset function. Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php

Comment: Thanks! will take a read into this, but I presume this wont show a remove button instead of an add button if the ID is currently in your session?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
session_start();
//if request parameter delete is present then unset the array
if(isset($_REQUEST['delete']))
{
    unset($_SESSION['event_orders']);
}   
else if(isset($_SESSION['event_orders']))
{
    //displays delete link which redirects to same page with an additional request parameter as url?delete
    echo "<a href='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?delete'>delete</a>";
}
else if(!in_array($_POST['event_id'], $_SESSION['event_orders'])) {
    $_SESSION['event_orders'][] = $_POST['event_id'];
}
?>
```

**EDIT:**
we need only to delete the specific array items instead of fully unseting the array.

```
<?php
session_start();
//if request parameter delete is present then unset the array
if(isset($_REQUEST['delete']))
{
    unset($_SESSION['event_orders'][$_REQUEST['delete']]);
    var_dump($_SESSION['event_orders']);
}   
else if(in_array($_POST['event_id'], $_SESSION['event_orders']))
{
    //displays delete link which redirects to same page with an additional request parameter as url?delete
    $key = array_search($_POST['event_id'], $_SESSION['event_orders']);
    var_dump($_SESSION['event_orders']);
    echo "<a href='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?delete=".$key."'>delete</a>";
}
else
{
    $_SESSION['event_orders'][] = $_POST['event_id'];
    var_dump($_SESSION['event_orders']);
}
?>
```

Comment: This code works but not sure if its perfect for my scenario.

Hold on still writting reply 2 secs

I have used this, and when it brings me to session.php (where the form gets sent to) it shows a delete button if the ID is in session (which is great) but I'd like that button to appear on the form page (which is currently just a  submit button, would something like this work (I will update in main post)